# Saleor - Docker - Error reading ./webpack-bundle.json

Tags: docker, webpack, saleor

**What I'm trying to achieve**

Follow the Saleor docker install instructions.

https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/docker.html#

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run web python3 manage.py migrate
docker-compose run web python3 manage.py collectstatic
docker-compose run web python3 manage.py populatedb --createsuperuser
docker-compose up
Goto http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

**What I expected to happen**

I expect to see the Saleor homepage

**What I actually happens**

```
Error reading ./webpack-bundle.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
```

**System information**

```
Operating system: MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3
Browser: Chrome 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Docker Engine: 18.06.0-ce
Docker Compose: 1.22.0
Docker Machine: 0.15.0
```

Running `yarn run build-assets` does not resolve the issue, as yarn is not installed on the docker container.

It seems that `/app/webpack-bundle.json` is not being copied from `build-nodejs (node:8.6.0)` as instructed in the `Dockerfile`.

`COPY --from=build-nodejs /app/webpack-bundle.json /app/`

npm run build-assets --production which runs webpack -p --progress should have created `/app/webpack-bundle.json`.

A log of the output of docker-compose up

`Step 25/35 : COPY --from=build-nodejs /app/webpack-bundle.json /app/   ---> 68c7bcd63e49`

and docker history shows the `/app/webpack-bundle.json` being copied to the container.

`68c7bcd63e49 20 minutes ago /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:8bbd3e3203b94232…   1.18kB`

https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/2506

Comment: This seems very specific to this application and not quite a programming question; if you duplicated your own GitHub question on SO then you'll probably get a better answer from the maintainer on GitHub.